# How to disable asserts without changing command line?

Tags: c++, debugging, assert

I have C++ code with asserts. When I compile the code with `g++ -D NDEBUG` option no assert commands are executed. But when I include NDEBUG on the code `#define NDEBUG` and compile it with no `-D NDEBUG` option, assert command are executed. How to disable asserts without changing command line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to define `NDEBUG` before including the header that defines `assert`.  Try

```
#define NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>
```

at the top of the source file you want to disable assertions in.

Answer (score 3):

By defining `NDEBUG`.  In practice, you would never compile with
`-D NDEBUG` in the command line; you should define your own
debug command, and then when the profiler shows you cannot
afford the checks in a specific function, wrap the function in
something like:

```
//  Non-critical code...

#ifdef MYDEBUGOFF
#define NDEBUG
#endif
#include <assert.h>

//  Critical function

#undef NDEBUG
#include <assert.h>

//  More non-critical code.
```

You can include `<assert.h>` as often as you like; each time it
redefines the `assert` macro according to whether `NDEBUG` is
defined at that moment.  So you can tune to your heart's
content; just `#define NDEBUG` or `#undef NDEBUG` each time
before you include the header.